# Solving $y'=\dfrac{2xy\exp(x/y)}{x^2+y^2\sin(x/y)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the ODE
$$y'=\dfrac{2xy\exp(x/y)}{x^2+y^2\sin(x/y)}$$

I tried two ways:
$$u=\frac{x}{y}\Rightarrow y'=\frac{u-xu'}{u^2}$$
and
$$u=\frac{1}{y}\Rightarrow y'=\frac{1}{u'}$$

In both cases, I didn't get a more simple equation to evaluate. Is there a better (and easier) way to find its solution?

Comment: You get a separable ODE with the first substitution. Carry out the corresponding calculations. You might be right that more can then not be done.

Comment: @04-jayeshkumargupta why isn't it homogeneous?

Comment: @LutzLehmann ah i am extremely sry abt that

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$x' = \frac{\frac{x^2}{y^2}+\sin\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}{2\frac{x}{y}\exp\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}$$

which can be rewritten as

$$yv'+v = \frac{v+\sin v}{2v\exp v}$$

with $x = yv$, which is a separable equation.

Comment: But why $x'$ since $y=y(x)$?

Comment: By the Implicit Function Theorem, if you're not near any singular points you can equivalently consider $y$ as a function of $x$ or $x$ as a function of $y$. The fact that the ugly part of the DE involves functions of $\frac{x}{y}$ suggests doing it that way around.